# Abstract enity with foreignkey to children enity

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, join, jpa-2.0

I work on model for item descriptions i've got enity DescriptionStringItem, DescriptionBigDecimalItem, etc... and anstract class AbstractDescriptionItem

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "description_abstract")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractDescriptionItem<T> implements Serializable 
{...}
```

and example DescriptionStringItem class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "description_string")
@AssociationOverride(name = "content_id", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_ds_ad_content_id")))
public class DescriptionStringItem extends AbstractDescriptionItem<String> 
{ ... }
```

Everything looks good in data base i got correct structure but parent tabel don't have id for children entity

parent entity

```
|           DESCRIPTION_ABSTRACT               |
|   ID   | ITEM_ID | **TYPE** | **CONTENT_ID** |
| 100000 | 1212    | ITEM_URL |      null      |
```

children entity

```
|           DESCRIPTION_STRING               |
|   ID   |        CONTENT   | 
| 100000 | www.google.pl    |
```

**UPDATE:**

Column **content_id** is useless i didn't know how it should work. Why and how it work without foreignkey ? im not sure, but in test and application i see all bag of my DescriptionItem :). So i remove column **content_id**.

I don't use auto create-update data base structure (hibernate).

Comment: it is pointless to mark title as `{SOLVED}`.  You may post an answer and accept it yourself, or if you don't think the question has any value to anyone else, just delete the question

Comment: Is the UPDATE a solution or do you still have a remaining question about this?

Comment: Is solution, but if some one know how it works, it will be great understand.